# How to move values of a row, from a column to another with a trigger function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-trigger, postgresql-9.3

I have two tables. A main table and a sort of "backup" table.

The main table looks like this:

```
  id   |   name   |   a   |   b   
  int  |   text   |  int  |  int   
-------+----------+-------+-------
  1    |   Joe    |  100  |  10   
  2    |   Bill   |  200  |  40  
  3    |   Frank  |  200  |  20   
  4    |   Jack   |  100  |  10
```

and the backup table looks like this:

```
  id   |   name1  |   a1  |   b1  |  name2 |  a2  | b2  |  name3 |  a3 | b3
  int  |   text   |  int  |  int  |  text  |  int | int |  text  | int | int 
-------+----------+-------+-------+--------+------+-----+--------+-----+----
  1    |   Joe    |  100  |  10   |        |      |     |        |     |
  2    |   Bill   |  200  |  40   |        |      |     |        |     |
  3    |   Frank  |  200  |  20   |        |      |     |        |     |
  4    |   Jack   |  100  |  10   |        |      |     |        |     |
```

What I would like here is if I update my main table (either the `name` or `a` or `b` column), the values in the backup table should move to the "next" columns. Like `name1` to `name2`, `a1` to `a2`, `b1` to `b2`, `name2` to `name3` etc. So for example if I update `Joe` to `Don`, the backup table would look like this:

```
UPDATE myschema.maintable
SET name = 'Don'
WHERE id = 1;
      id   |   name1  |   a1  |   b1  |  name2 |  a2  | b2  |  name3 |  a3 | b3
      int  |   text   |  int  |  int  |  text  |  int | int |  text  | int | int 
    -------+----------+-------+-------+--------+------+-----+--------+-----+----
      1    |   Don    |  100  |  10   |  Joe   | 100  | 10  |        |     |
      2    |   Bill   |  200  |  40   |        |      |     |        |     |
      3    |   Frank  |  200  |  20   |        |      |     |        |     |
      4    |   Jack   |  100  |  10   |        |      |     |        |     |
```

Now I know that this is a quite bad way to do a backup table, but unfortunately it is beyond my control, and this is how I have to do it.

What I have tried and expected to work is this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_update_func()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
UPDATE myschema.backuptable
SET 
name3 = name2,
a3 = a2,
b3 = b2,
name2 = name1,
b2 = a1,
b2 = b1,
name1 = name,
a1 = a,
b1 = b
FROM myschema.maintable
WHERE maintable.id = backuptable.id;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE

CREATE TRIGGER table_update_trig
BEFORE UPDATE 
ON myschema.maintable
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (OLD.* IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.*)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE table_update_func();
```

If I update something in the `maintale` it runs without an error, but it moves the columns in every row, not just the one I updated. Where did I go wrong? I am pretty sure my condition `WHERE maintable.id = backup.id;` is not good, but I don't know how should I solve this problem.

Comment: One obvious limitation in your design is that the suggested table only has a "memory" of the last two versions.  Instead, I suggest versioning the records themselves, in your original table.

Comment: Yes I know it is limiterd, but actually there are several more columns for the versions, Ijust wanted to simplify my problem. Unfortunately I cannot change the structure of either table. That's why I have to do this version backup in a not so logical way.

Comment: Why not you are going for a history table?

Comment: Are you really still using Postgres 9.3? It is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: @mkRabbani Because I got this problem as a task at my workplace and as I said, I have to do it using these two tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes we are really still using 9.3. That's an other thing that is beyond my control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining the backup table with every row in the maintable that's why you always update all rows in the backup table. You don't need a FROM clause there, as you have the ID of the UPDATE row available in the `new` record.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_update_func()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
UPDATE myschema.backuptable 
  SET name3 = name2,
      a3 = a2,
      b3 = b2,
      name2 = name1,
      b2 = a1,
      b2 = b1,
      name1 = new.name, -- reference the values of the new record here
      a1 = new.a,
      b1 = new.b
  WHERE backuptable.id = new.id; --<< no FROM clause necessary
  
  RETURN new; --<< IMPORTANT for a BEFORE UPDATE trigger!
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```